# Can I copy :OLD and :NEW pseudo-records in/to an Oracle stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, triggers

I have an `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE` trigger that I'm writing to store every record revision that occurs in a certain table, by copying the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` `:NEW` values into a mirror table, and for `DELETE` the `:OLD` values.

I could un-clutter my code considerably by conditionally passing either the `:NEW` or `:OLD` record into a procedure which would then do the insert into my history table.  Unfortunately I cannot seem to find a way to pass the entire `:OLD` or `:NEW` record.

Am I missing something or is there no way to avoid enumerating every `:NEW` and `:OLD` column as I invoke my insert procedure?

I want to do the following:

```
DECLARE
  PROCEDURE LOCAL_INSERT(historyRecord in ACCT.ACCOUNTS%ROWTYPE) IS
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ACCT.ACCOUNTS_HISTORY (ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, DATE) VALUES (historyRecord.ID, historyRecord.NAME, historyRecord.DESCRIPTION, SYSDATE);
  END;
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN
    LOCAL_INSERT(:NEW);
  ELSE --DELETING
    LOCAL_INSERT(:OLD);
  END IF;
END;
```

But I'm stuck doing this:

```
DECLARE
  PROCEDURE LOCAL_INSERT(id in ACCT.ACCOUNTS.ID%TYPE,
                         name in ACCT.ACCOUNTS.NAME%TYPE,
                         description in ACCT.ACCOUNTS.DESCRIPTION%TYPE) IS
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ACCT.ACCOUNTS_HISTORY (ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, DATE) VALUES (id, name, description, SYSDATE);
  END;
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN
    LOCAL_INSERT(:NEW.ID, :NEW.NAME, :NEW.DESCRIPTION);
  ELSE --DELETING
    LOCAL_INSERT(:OLD.ID, :OLD.NAME, :OLD.DESCRIPTION);
  END IF;
END;
```

Okay, so it doesn't look like a big difference, but this is just an example with 3 columns rather than dozens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't.  You have to do it yourself through enumeration.

The reasons it can't/doesn't work automatically include:

- the `:old` and `:new` are default conventions; you can name the `:old` and `:new` references to be whatever you want through the `REFERENCING` clause of the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement.
- you'd have to have a public declaration of a type (through `CREATE TYPE` or through a package declaration) to be able to use it as an argument to another piece of code.
- trigger code is interpreted code, not compiled code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible like that. [Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm) doesn't mention anything like that.

This would certainly cost performance, but you could try to define your trigger `AFTER INSERT` and another one `BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE`, and in the trigger do something like:

```
SELECT *
INTO rowtype_variable
FROM accounts
WHERE accounts.id = :NEW.id; -- :OLD.id for UPDATE and DELETE
```

and then call your procedure with that `rowtype_variable`.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL to generate the SQL;

```
select ' row_field.'||COLUMN_NAME||' := :new.'||COLUMN_NAME||';'  from 
    ALL_TAB_COLUMNS cols 
where 
    cols.TABLE_NAME = 'yourTableName'
order by cols.column_name.
```

Then copy and paste output.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ***AFTER*** trigger you can use rowid as parameter to call procedure

```
insert into t_hist
select * from t where rowid = r;
```

If you use ***BEFORE*** trigger you will get **ORA-04091** mutating table, ***BUT*** you solution can be (http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_avoiding_mutating_table_error.htm):

- Don't use triggers - The best way to avoid the mutating table error is not to use triggers.  While the object-oriented Oracle provides "methods" that are associated with tables, most savvy PL/SQL developers avoid triggers unless absolutely necessary.
- Use an "after" or "instead of" trigger - If you must use a trigger, it's best to avoid the mutating table error by using an "after" trigger, to avoid the currency issues associated with a mutating table.  For example, using a trigger ":after update on xxx", the original update has completed and the table will not be mutating.
- Re-work the trigger syntax - Dr. Hall has some great notes on mutating table errors, and offers other ways to avoid mutating tables with a combination of row-level and statement-level triggers.
- Use autonomous transactions - You can avoid the mutating table error by marking your trigger as an autonomous transaction, making it independent from the table that calls the procedure.