# Oracle PL/SQL: Forwarding whole row to procedure from a trigger

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, triggers

In have an Oracle (10i) PL/SQL Row-Level trigger which is responsible for three independent tasks. As the trigger is relatively cluttered that way, I want to export these three tasks into three stored procedures.
I was thinking of using a `my_table%ROWTYPE` parameter or maybe a collection type for the procedures, but my main concern is how to fill these parameters.

Is there a way to put the whole `:NEW` row of a trigger into a single variable easily? 
So far the only way I could find out was assigning each field separately to the variable which is not quite satisfying, looking at code maintenance etc.

Something like

```
SELECT :NEW.* INTO <variable> FROM dual;
```

would be preferred. (I haven't tried that actually but I suppose it wouldn't work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible that way.

Maybe [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337325/can-i-copy-old-and-new-pseudo-records-in-to-an-oracle-stored-procedure/2337445#2337445) can help.

Comment: Unfortunately, i need to stick to the BEFORE I/U/D FOR EACH ROW trigger for this specific code. But stating that it is not possible to copy the whole row at once  answered my question I guess ;-)

Answer (score 9):

In the vast majority of cases, the only way to assign the new values in the row to a %ROWTYPE variable would be to explicitly assign each column.  Something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER some_trigger_name
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON some_table
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  l_row some_table%rowtype;
BEGIN
  l_row.column1 := :NEW.column1;
  l_row.column2 := :NEW.column2;
  ...
  l_row.columnN := :NEW.columnN;

  procedure1( l_row );
  procedure2( l_row );
  procedure3( l_row );
END;
```

If your table happens to be declared based on an object, :NEW will be an object of that type.  So if you have a table like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE obj_foo 
    AS OBJECT (
      column1 NUMBER,
      column2 NUMBER,
      ...
      columnN NUMBER );

CREATE TABLE foo OF obj_foo;
```

then you could declare procedures that accept input parameters of type `OBJ_FOO` and call those directly from your trigger.

The suggestion in the other thread about selecting the row from the table in an AFTER INSERT/ UPDATE thread, unfortunately, does not generally work.  That will generally lead to a mutating table exception.

```
  1  create table foo (
  2    col1 number,
  3    col2 number
  4* )
SQL> /

Table created.

SQL> create procedure foo_proc( p_foo in foo%rowtype )
  2  as
  3  begin
  4    dbms_output.put_line( 'In foo_proc' );
  5  end;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_foo
  2    after insert or update on foo
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    l_row foo%rowtype;
  6  begin
  7    select *
  8      into l_row
  9      from foo
 10     where col1 = :new.col1;
 11    foo_proc( l_row );
 12  end;
 13  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into foo values( 1, 2 );
insert into foo values( 1, 2 )
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04091: table SCOTT.FOO is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_FOO", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_FOO'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use SQL to generate the SQL;

```
select ' row_field.'||COLUMN_NAME||' := :new.'||COLUMN_NAME||';'  from 
     ALL_TAB_COLUMNS cols 
where 
     cols.TABLE_NAME = 'yourTableName'
order by cols.column_name
```

Then copy and paste output.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Justins solution but a little bit shorter (no typing of left part of each assignment) :

```
-- use instead of the assignments in Justins example:
select :new.column1, 
       :new.column2,
...
       :new.columnN,
into l_row from dual;
```

Comment: It just occurred to me that my solution is dependent on the order of columns in the table.