# In an Oracle trigger, can I assign new and old to a rowtype variable?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I've been tasked with implementing several trigger scripts, and I've got examples from coworkers to work from. In those, they use pl-sql conditionals for updating/inserting/deleting, along with gigantic insert statements (in another table). These insert statements do not vary other than whether the values are prefixed with new or old. I thought I would be clever and try to make mine a little more compact, using the following:

```
DECLARE
  vRow SATURN.SPRCMNT%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

  IF UPDATING THEN
    vRow := :NEW;
  ELSIF INSERTING THEN
    vRow := :NEW;
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
    vRow := :OLD;
  END IF;

  -- Not the real insert statement
  INSERT INTO blah 
    (columns)
    VALUES
    (vRow.somecolumns);

END;
```

I get the following back from the compile system:

```
10/13  PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW'
13/13  PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW'
16/13  PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD'
```

Obviously it does not like this. Is there something that will achieve what I'm attempting? Are :new and :old just not true rowtypes? It seems dumb to repeat what is essentially the same code 3 times over, and yet I can't figure out a better way. Hell, I think I read that there's some hard limit on the size of triggers too. Any help appreciated.

[Edit] Just a thought, is it possible to reference the UPDATING/INSERTING keywords somehow within a DECODE()?

For instance, if I could do a DECODE(SOMETHINGVAR, UPDATING, :NEW.column, DELETING, :OLD.column) then I could set the value of each column in vRow with a single statement.

I guess it'd be better to check DELETING first, and use the default for the other two.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can't do it - check answers in [this stack overflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337325/can-i-copy-old-and-new-pseudo-records-in-to-an-oracle-stored-procedure).

Comment: It seems that `DECODE(UPDATING...` doesn't work, however there is a workaround, look at this demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8ad9e/1 it may help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't.  `:new` and `:old` are pseudo-records, not actual records that you can assign to a local variable.  If your tables were based on object types, `:new` and `:old` would then be actual instances of the particular object type that can be passed around like any other object.  But it's pretty unlikely that it is worth defining your tables in terms of objects just to make your triggers easier to write.

You could, of course, write a PL/SQL package that automatically generates the trigger code you want by doing things like querying the data dictionary (i.e. `all_tab_columns` to get the list of columns in a table) ans using dynamic SQL.  Depending on the number of triggers you expect to have to write, this may be easier than writing and maintaining a ton of similar code.

Comment: Yeh, actually I am writing a procedure to generate the trigger code, I expect to have to do more in the future. Just wanted to get the trigger code right before I start auto-generating it. There are at least 4 older bugs completed by coworkers, and 3 assigned to me right now. I think that's past the threshold for automation.

Answer (score 5):

I've decided to answer on this question as I'd heard it many times and never seen any solution.

So the idea is to have one generic "structure independent" trigger calling some PL/SQL procedure passing entire new and old row.

I used object table for that.

```
create or replace type test_table_type as object(
  ... your attributes ....
);

create table test of test_table_type;

create or replace trigger trg_test_upd
before update on test
for each row
  l_new_row  test_table_type;
  l_old_row  test_table_type;
  l_row_id   raw(40000);
begin
  l_new_row := :new.sys_nc_rowinfo$; -- <-- this is your new row
  l_old_row := :old.sys_nc_rowinfo$; -- <-- this is your old row
  l_row_id :=  :old.sys_nc_oid$; -- <-- this your row logical ID (not rowid!!!). You can use it if you don't have primary key or it is composite.
  -- here you can do what ever you want with you old/new rows.
  ...
end;
/
```

I like this method as it allows to define common attributes in base type and inherit other types from this type. So you can use generic code even for many tables based on same base type.

Comment: Thank you. I've since implemented a different solution, but this is a recurring issue... eventually I'll get another opportunity to to try this. It's much appreciated.