# How to get all the new values in oracle trigger using :NEW or :OLD operator. like (:NEW.*)

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle12c

I am trying to get all the new values and old values in trigger before inserting it to another table but i could just get the specific value not the all the data.

I tried with :NEW.* and :OLD.* it works fine for postgress but not for oracle.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_customer_tbl_ib01
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON TEST.customer_test
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
vAction VARCHAR2(4000) := null;
vFound INT := null;
vREC TEST.CUSTOMER_TEST%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN
select :NEW.* into vREC FROM DUAL;
ELSIF DELETING THEN
select :OLD.* into vREC FROM DUAL;
END IF;
IF DELETING THEN
INSERT INTO TEST.CUSTOMER_TEST_AUDIT SELECT 
CUSTOMER_TEST_AUDIT_id_seq.NEXTVAL,'D',SYSDATE, vREC.* FROM  DUAL;
ELSIF UPDATING THEN
INSERT INTO TEST.CUSTOMER_TEST_AUDIT SELECT 
CUSTOMER_TEST_AUDIT_id_seq.NEXTVAL,'U',SYSDATE, vREC.*FROM  DUAL;
ELSIF INSERTING THEN
INSERT INTO TEST.CUSTOMER_TEST_AUDIT SELECT 
CUSTOMER_TEST_AUDIT_id_seq.NEXTVAL,'I',SYSDATE, vREC.* FROM  DUAL;
END IF;
END;
```

I am getting error :
Error(10,8): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In an Oracle trigger, can I assign new and old to a rowtype variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610295/in-an-oracle-trigger-can-i-assign-new-and-old-to-a-rowtype-variable)

Comment: I don't want to create table as object just for shake of it. I am trying to get the column  name and append it with :NEW.col_name from all_tab_columns but i am not able to append it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, don't be impatient. Don't use shortcuts.

Test case:

```
SQL> create table test as select * From dept;

Table created.

SQL> create table test_log as select * From dept where 1 = 2;

Table created.

SQL> alter table test_log add (id number, action varchar2(1), datum date);

Table altered.

SQL> create sequence seqlog;

Sequence created.

SQL>
```

Trigger. Reference each column separately. The fact that `:NEW.*` works in Postgres doesn't mean it works in Oracle.

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_test
  2    before insert or update or delete on test
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    if updating then
  6       insert into test_log (deptno, dname, loc, id, action, datum)
  7         values
  8         (:old.deptno, :old.dname, :old.loc, seqlog.nextval, 'U', sysdate);
  9       insert into test_log (deptno, dname, loc, id, action, datum)
 10         values
 11         (:new.deptno, :new.dname, :new.loc, seqlog.nextval, 'U', sysdate);
 12    elsif inserting then
 13       insert into test_log (deptno, dname, loc, id, action, datum)
 14         values
 15         (:new.deptno, :new.dname, :new.loc, seqlog.nextval, 'I', sysdate);
 16    elsif deleting then
 17       insert into test_log (deptno, dname, loc, id, action, datum)
 18         values
 19         (:old.deptno, :old.dname, :old.loc, seqlog.nextval, 'D', sysdate);
 20    end if;
 21  end;
 22  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Testing:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_Date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> update test set loc = 'Croatia' where deptno = 10;

1 row updated.

SQL> delete from test where deptno = 20;

1 row deleted.

SQL> insert into test (deptno, dname, loc) values (99, 'IT', 'Zagreb');

1 row created.

SQL> select * From test_log order by id;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC                   ID A DATUM
---------- -------------- ------------- ---------- - -------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK               5 U 20.05.2019 21:44:33
        10 ACCOUNTING     Croatia                6 U 20.05.2019 21:44:33
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS                 7 D 20.05.2019 21:44:43
        99 IT             Zagreb                 8 I 20.05.2019 21:44:52

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. The problem here is there is not just one or two table there are more than 1000 tables. I am just testing it for 1 table I have to make it generic  for all the table. Some how i need to get all the columns dynamically.

Comment: You're welcome. Well, auditing 1000 tables that way is probably not the best approach. I presume you *could* use dynamic SQL, but that doesn't scale well. Did you consider using something that Oracle offers itself for such a purpose, and it is called (who'd guess) *auditing*. More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/auditing.htm#DBSEG1023